Is rotary motion on an organic being possible?
One huge advantage that machines have over animals is that they can efficiently perform continuous rotary motion, which allows for things like wheels, drills and so on.
In fact, rotary motion is so easy to implement for machines that it's the main form of motion most motors use.
Would this be possible on an organic being? And if so, how?

This is trivially provable: the flagellum on a mammalian sperm cell (and possibly the sperm of other phyla, as well as a number of single-cell animals) is a rotary propeller, with a molecular scale bearing and motor that spin the fiber to propel the sperm in a fluid environment.

Are you sure that flagella of spermatozoa have a rotary motion? AFAIK they have a whip-like wavy motion.

Yes, I am sure.  The movement looks like wavy motion because you can't see it in 3D, but it's a helical tail structure (or more correctly angled to the rotation axis and drawn into a helical shape by fluid resistance) that seems to pass waves along its length as it spins.  This has been proven by high-resolution imaging and molecular analysis of the motor/bearing structures.  I read about it in Scientific American as far back as the 1980s.

In general this doesn't work because the components wheel and axle do not have a permanent link which means an organic being can't exchange nutrients between the two pieces.
However, this also hints at how you could have such an effect: the wheel is just dead matter, like a tooth, horn or hair. This means that while the wheel grows, it is still connected to the body of the being and can't rotate. Only once it is fully grown and formed will it disconnect and become a rotating wheel.

A little sparse for an answer, but essentially what i would have said. Might want to flesh it out as practice.

The axle could be a hollow pipe with an airtight, oiled connection to the wheel, so that the wheel can rotate while nutrient fluid flows through the center of the axle without spilling too much. Alternatively the nutrient connection through the axle could detach and seal up when it's time for the wheel to spin, and reattach when the wheel is stationary.

Or instead of an axle nutrient connection, the body could have a separate needle-like appendage for transferring blood intravenously to the wheel, which it only uses while the wheel is stationary.

a simple form of that could be a clam or a snail that "rolls" on a big pearl it produced. I imagine something between an escargot snail, a clam and an old-shool ball-based computer mouse.

The closest your probably going to come to rotational motors in living organisms (as currently understood based on the Earths life forms) are summarized in Wikipedia here:
In particular I would refer you to the section on Axonemes or to be precise axial filaments which are the core structures behind the development of cilium and flagellum used by micro organisms on Earth to move through (primarily) aqueous environments.
Follow all the links and you'll see that Bacterial flagella use a form of molecular based rotary movement to produce propulsion.  As you'll also see however the 'machines'/forces concerned are very low powered and (based on all the evidence we have) never translated into useful work or movement in higher lifeforms. By which I mean there's no evidence rotational forces ever evolved in more advanced (complex life forms) as a  means of movement or other effective 'work'. This probably indicates its impractical at any scale above simple, single celled or basic multi-cellular lifeforms.
EDIT: as per the previous post about sperm cells my answer relates to large/complex organisms as a whole.
